# UICollectionView content offset changes on app going to background and rotating device

Tags: ios, uicollectionview, landscape-portrait

I have UICollectionView with paging. The cell is the size of the screen, so I have one cell per page. I have `collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, targetContentOffsetForProposedContentOffset proposedContentOffset: CGPoint) -> CGPoint` implemented. When device is in foreground rotation works well.
But when the app goes to background and the device changes orientation and the app comes back to foreground there are already two partially visible cells. What I need is the same cell to show that was visible before going to background. The size of the cells is correct. Only the offset is wrong. I tried saving the last cell index before going to background and scrolling to it on coming to foreground but I still have the issue if when in background the home button is double clicked to see the open apps - the app will show with the two partially visible cells. Here is some of the code, but this code does not seem to be called when the app is in background and the device rotates:

```
extension SlideshowViewController : UICollectionViewDelegate {
    func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, layout collectionViewLayout: UICollectionViewLayout, sizeForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> CGSize {
        return collectionView.frame.size
    }

    func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, targetContentOffsetForProposedContentOffset proposedContentOffset: CGPoint) -> CGPoint {

        let width = collectionView.frame.size.width
        let visibleCells = collectionView.visibleCells
        if visibleCells.count == 0 {
            return CGPoint.zero
        }
        let cell = visibleCells[0]
        let indexPath = collectionView.indexPath(for: cell)
        let index = indexPath?.item
        let offsetX = CGFloat(index!) * width
        let offsetY: CGFloat = 0
        let offset = CGPoint(x: offsetX, y: offsetY)

        return offset

    }
}
```

Comment: try to invalidate the collectionviewlayout using -----      self.collectionView.collectionViewLayout.invalidateLayout()

Comment: @AnkitKumarGupta I tried that but it does not solve it.

Comment: Share the code will try to help you out. (Make a demo project and share the zip)